# How can I set grep to default to a certain filename pattern?

Tags: windows-7, grep

I work in python, so 95% or more of the time my grep search is

```
grep "thing to find" *.py
```

or something similar. I'm working in Windows 7, but being a unix guy, I am lazy with my keystrokes, so I would like to set grep to automatically search `*.py` unless I specify something different.

Is there anything I can add to `GREP_OPTIONS` to do this?  Or something similar?

Comment: @slyx that should be an answer, but with `"$@"` instead of `$1`.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks, I noticed the difference! I've just  posted it as an answer !

Comment: Ah, left out a little detail.  I'm working on a Win7 box most of the time.   So no functions.  I can put it in a batch file {grep %1 *.py}   which is better than nothing.  I just was hoping for a more canonical/config file or environment variable type solution.

Comment: @SkipHuffman, In windows envirenement (MSDOS) you can also define a DOSKEY macro : `DOSKEY pygrep=grep $* *.py` and call it the same way you see in the answers. unfortunately DOSKEY and BATCH parameters number is limited to 9 in Windows environment so don't forget to use `pygrep "Your search between double quote limiters"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a mini batch file:

```
grep -n "%*" *.py
```

saves a few keystrokes, and matches my normal brain cycle.  "Where is this phrase in my python code?"

Thanks everyone for the input!

Answer (score 5):

You can define a function pygrep which will search inside your `py` files only :

```
pygrep() { 
    grep "$@" *.py
}
```

Comment: @jordanm Thanks for the POSIX compliant edit !

Answer (score 1):

Create a function

```
mygrep(){ grep "$@" *.py}
```

Run it

```
mygrep main
```

Add the function to your login startup file.

Comment: What's the point of the alias? Why not just call the function `mygrep` and be done with it?

Comment: My function names tend to be long but my aliases short. I did say it was optional.

Comment: Yes you did, I was just wondering why you would want the alias at all, it seems to simply add a layer of complexity without doing anything useful. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's probably because I started defining aliases and then functions came along, adding *that layer of complexity*. So it's a bit of an old habit.

Comment: Ah, yes, I know all about old habits :). So aliases predate functions? I had no idea.

Comment: @terdon I am going to guess no, since `alias` wasn't added to the POSIX spec until 2004.

Comment: @jordanm from the csh manual page, under BUGS, "Alias substitution is most often used to clumsily simulate shell procedures; shell procedures should be provided rather than aliases."

Comment: csh is not POSIX compliant.